# SUMIF with an unspecific value

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I wish to sum all fields in a given range of a certain type, when I have a table of that form:

```
Type     Sum

Type1_y  12

Type2    52

Type3    3

Type1_x  18
```

I would like to sum all values of type Type1_???. (e.g. in this example above, the answer should be 30 = 18 + 12)

Can I do that in Google sheets?

Comment: Just to clarify, does your data look like [this](https://imgur.com/a/E0M0ZMm)? If so, you can use the SUMIF function.

Comment: I hope it is clearer now. My data is similar, only that I don't know that *exact* value of the first column, but instead just that it starts with "Type1_" (and then multiple things may follow)

Comment: Yes much better thanks. Are you open to creating a new column with helper data? If so, I would add a column with a formula like `=left(A1,5)` and use that column in your SUMIF. Otherwise, I'm not sure how this could be done using SUMIF.

Comment: Sure, that does solve my problem. Thanks!
Please write it as an answer, and I will mark my question as answered. :)
Although, if there is a direct way to do that (e.g. with a regular expression), that would be great too.

Comment: Yes you can do that! Try something like `=SUMIF($A:$A,"Type1_*",$B:$B)`. The asterisk matches any characters following `Type1_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `=SUMIF($A:$A,"Type1_*",$B:$B)`. The asterisk matches any characters following `Type1_`.

Answer (score 2):

also works:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:B, "select B where A starts with 'Type1_'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:B, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "^Type1_")))
```

[image: 0]